# Table with 100% width that leaves room for floating div

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I have a table that I'm using for a form. The solution needs it to be adjustable automatically to two scenarios:

- When there is no floating div to the right of the table, I want the
  table to take up 100% of the width.
- When there is a floating div to the right of the table, I want the table to give room for this div, and take up the remaining horizontal space.

How can I do this?

Comment: will your div have fixed width?

Comment: 100% width is non-negotiable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the table in a div with an `overflow` that is not `visible` and it will take up the remaining area next to the floated element. Then, the table inside that can have a `width:100%`. The code is below and here's an example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/uEt35/

*CSS*

```
.floater {
    float:right;
}

.tbl-container {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.tbl-container > table {
    width:100%;
}
```

*HTML*

```
​<div class="floater">
   This is to the right.
</div>
<div class="tbl-container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>hi</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work if you have to create a general CSS file, which shall be applied to any unknown content, depending on the editors. That is the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the div to the right using

```
display:none;
```

You can reserve its space using

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Your table will have a width of 100% so when the div is display:none, the div will not take up space and the table will expand naturally. If you only hide the div the table will maintain a smaller width based on the width of the div to the right.

This info is available at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)